# flutter MatrixGestureDetector on scale all emoji become large and jump in screen

Tags: android, flutter, transform, scale, matrixgesturedetector

what is the problem with this code?

I want emojis also scale with text correctly like text but the emoji jump and become large

if I put only the emoji also the same problem happened

[image]

> main.dart

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),  
    body: SizedBox(
      height: Get.height,
      width: Get.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          TransformDemo(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

> transform_demo.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_editor/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

class TransformDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
        notifier.value = m;
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: notifier,
        builder: (ctx, child) {
          return Transform(
            transform: notifier.value,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: FittedBox(
                // fit: BoxFit.contain,
                child: Text('Hello world  ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),)
                // child: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.5), size: 200),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> matrix_gesture_detector.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

typedef MatrixGestureDetectorCallback = void Function(
    Matrix4 matrix,
    Matrix4 translationDeltaMatrix,
    Matrix4 scaleDeltaMatrix,
    Matrix4 rotationDeltaMatrix);

/// [MatrixGestureDetector] detects translation, scale and rotation gestures
/// and combines them into [Matrix4] object that can be used by [Transform] widget
/// or by low level [CustomPainter] code. You can customize types of reported
/// gestures by passing [shouldTranslate], [shouldScale] and [shouldRotate]
/// parameters.
///
class MatrixGestureDetector extends StatefulWidget {
  /// [Matrix4] change notification callback
  ///
  final MatrixGestureDetectorCallback onMatrixUpdate;

  /// The [child] contained by this detector.
  ///
  /// {@macro flutter.widgets.child}
  ///
  final Widget child;

  /// Whether to detect translation gestures during the event processing.
  ///
  /// Defaults to true.
  ///
  final bool shouldTranslate;

  /// Whether to detect scale gestures during the event processing.
  ///
  /// Defaults to true.
  ///
  final bool shouldScale;

  /// Whether to detect rotation gestures during the event processing.
  ///
  /// Defaults to true.
  ///
  final bool shouldRotate;

  /// Whether [ClipRect] widget should clip [child] widget.
  ///
  /// Defaults to true.
  ///
  final bool clipChild;

  /// The hit test behavior, passed to the underlying GestureDetector.
  ///
  /// Defaults to HitTestBehavior.deferToChild
  ///
  final HitTestBehavior behavior;

  /// When set, it will be used for computing a "fixed" focal point
  /// aligned relative to the size of this widget.
  final Alignment? focalPointAlignment;

  const MatrixGestureDetector({
    Key? key,
    required this.onMatrixUpdate,
    required this.child,
    this.shouldTranslate = true,
    this.shouldScale = true,
    this.shouldRotate = true,
    this.clipChild = true,
    this.focalPointAlignment,
    this.behavior = HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
  })  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MatrixGestureDetectorState createState() => _MatrixGestureDetectorState();

  ///
  /// Compose the matrix from translation, scale and rotation matrices - you can
  /// pass a null to skip any matrix from composition.
  ///
  /// If [matrix] is not null the result of the composing will be concatenated
  /// to that [matrix], otherwise the identity matrix will be used.
  ///
  static Matrix4 compose(Matrix4? matrix, Matrix4? translationMatrix,
      Matrix4? scaleMatrix, Matrix4? rotationMatrix) {
    if (matrix == null) matrix = Matrix4.identity();
    if (translationMatrix != null) matrix = translationMatrix * matrix;
    if (scaleMatrix != null) matrix = scaleMatrix * matrix;
    if (rotationMatrix != null) matrix = rotationMatrix * matrix;
    return matrix!;
  }

  ///
  /// Decomposes [matrix] into [MatrixDecomposedValues.translation],
  /// [MatrixDecomposedValues.scale] and [MatrixDecomposedValues.rotation] components.
  ///
  static MatrixDecomposedValues decomposeToValues(Matrix4 matrix) {
    var array = matrix.applyToVector3Array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);
    Offset translation = Offset(array[0], array[1]);
    Offset delta = Offset(array[3] - array[0], array[4] - array[1]);
    double scale = delta.distance;
    double rotation = delta.direction;
    return MatrixDecomposedValues(translation, scale, rotation);
  }
}

class _MatrixGestureDetectorState extends State<MatrixGestureDetector> {
  Matrix4 translationDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
  Matrix4 scaleDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
  Matrix4 rotationDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child =
    widget.clipChild ? ClipRect(child: widget.child) : widget.child;
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: widget.behavior,
      onScaleStart: onScaleStart,
      onScaleUpdate: onScaleUpdate,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  _ValueUpdater<Offset> translationUpdater = _ValueUpdater(
    value: Offset.zero,
    onUpdate: (oldVal, newVal) => newVal - oldVal,
  );
  _ValueUpdater<double> scaleUpdater = _ValueUpdater(
    value: 1.0,
    onUpdate: (oldVal, newVal) => newVal / oldVal,
  );
  _ValueUpdater<double> rotationUpdater = _ValueUpdater(
    value: 0.0,
    onUpdate: (oldVal, newVal) => newVal - oldVal,
  );

  void onScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    translationUpdater.value = details.focalPoint;
    scaleUpdater.value = 1.0;
    rotationUpdater.value = 0.0;
  }

  void onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    translationDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
    scaleDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
    rotationDeltaMatrix = Matrix4.identity();

    // handle matrix translating
    if (widget.shouldTranslate) {
      Offset translationDelta = translationUpdater.update(details.focalPoint);
      translationDeltaMatrix = _translate(translationDelta);
      matrix = translationDeltaMatrix * matrix;
    }

    final focalPointAlignment = widget.focalPointAlignment;
    final focalPoint = focalPointAlignment == null ?
    details.localFocalPoint :
    focalPointAlignment.alongSize(context.size!);

    // handle matrix scaling
    if (widget.shouldScale && details.scale != 1.0) {
      double scaleDelta = scaleUpdater.update(details.scale);
      scaleDeltaMatrix = _scale(scaleDelta, focalPoint);
      matrix = scaleDeltaMatrix * matrix;
    }

    // handle matrix rotating
    if (widget.shouldRotate && details.rotation != 0.0) {
      double rotationDelta = rotationUpdater.update(details.rotation);
      rotationDeltaMatrix = _rotate(rotationDelta, focalPoint);
      matrix = rotationDeltaMatrix * matrix;
    }

    widget.onMatrixUpdate(
        matrix, translationDeltaMatrix, scaleDeltaMatrix, rotationDeltaMatrix);
  }

  Matrix4 _translate(Offset translation) {
    var dx = translation.dx;
    var dy = translation.dy;

    //  ..[0]  = 1       # x scale
    //  ..[5]  = 1       # y scale
    //  ..[10] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    //  ..[12] = dx      # x translation
    //  ..[13] = dy      # y translation
    //  ..[15] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    return Matrix4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1);
  }

  Matrix4 _scale(double scale, Offset focalPoint) {
    var dx = (1 - scale) * focalPoint.dx;
    var dy = (1 - scale) * focalPoint.dy;

    //  ..[0]  = scale   # x scale
    //  ..[5]  = scale   # y scale
    //  ..[10] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    //  ..[12] = dx      # x translation
    //  ..[13] = dy      # y translation
    //  ..[15] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    return Matrix4(scale, 0, 0, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1);
  }

  Matrix4 _rotate(double angle, Offset focalPoint) {
    var c = cos(angle);
    var s = sin(angle);
    var dx = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dx + s * focalPoint.dy;
    var dy = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dy - s * focalPoint.dx;

    //  ..[0]  = c       # x scale
    //  ..[1]  = s       # y skew
    //  ..[4]  = -s      # x skew
    //  ..[5]  = c       # y scale
    //  ..[10] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    //  ..[12] = dx      # x translation
    //  ..[13] = dy      # y translation
    //  ..[15] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    return Matrix4(c, s, 0, 0, -s, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1);
  }
}

typedef _OnUpdate<T> = T Function(T oldValue, T newValue);

class _ValueUpdater<T> {
  final _OnUpdate<T> onUpdate;
  T value;

  _ValueUpdater({
    required this.value,
    required this.onUpdate,
  });

  T update(T newValue) {
    T updated = onUpdate(value, newValue);
    value = newValue;
    return updated;
  }
}

class MatrixDecomposedValues {
  /// Translation, in most cases useful only for matrices that are nothing but
  /// a translation (no scale and no rotation).
  final Offset translation;

  /// Scaling factor.
  final double scale;

  /// Rotation in radians, (-pi..pi) range.
  final double rotation;

  MatrixDecomposedValues(this.translation, this.scale, this.rotation);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MatrixDecomposedValues(translation: $translation, scale: ${scale.toStringAsFixed(3)}, rotation: ${rotation.toStringAsFixed(3)})';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing, is caused by a known issue in the current version of Flutter. When the text is too big, the emoji gets huge.

To reproduce it, you simply need to make the text big:

```
Text(
  'Hi  ',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
),
```

Sample output:

[image: a text with a huge emoji]

See issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110726. For now, I'd say just stay tuned for the flutter team to patch it.

Comment: i found the problem is with flutter version

Comment: @FaizAhmadDae yes exactly, what you described in your question, is ultimately caused by this known issue